# How to Curve a bitmap in android

Tags: android, bitmap, bit-manipulation, curve

I am developing a game and I want to give a smoke effect at the tail of the objects moving freely on the screen. I just created a bitmap and attached it at the end of object but the problem is that this doesn't look good because when the objects turns towards a new angle the effect doesn't curve it self. All I want is to know that how can I do this? Is there any possibility to give curve to the bitmap or another solution? I want to give a smoke effect at the tail of a bike. I hope someone will provide me a solution. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Finally I got the answer myself so sharing it with you.
What I wanted was to give a smoke effect at the tail of a moving object such that when the object take turns in screen the tail should do the same. 
What I do us that I take four bitmap images which gives a smoke effect when combined.
I recorded the points X and Y which the boat has passed from and then drew the bitmap on these points which solved my problem. I hope it will help someone else someday so I shared it.
Thanks